# No output of strange output (SQL/PHP)

Tags: php, sql

Hello I made a script what combinate two id's to one id and thene compare it to a price. And the output will be the id and the price.

But the script does work for 99% but the out put is Array and not a price. What did I do wrong?

```
<?php //data.php
require_once 'login.php'; 

// Get values from form
$Fname       = $_POST['first_name'];
$Lname       = $_POST['last_name']; 
$sex         = $_POST['sex'];   
$email       = $_POST['email'];
$password    = $_POST['password']; 

$data1 = $Lname;
$data2 = $sex;
$id =  $data1 . $data2;

$query =  "
SELECT prijs
FROM prijzen
WHERE broodje='".$id."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);



// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, sex, email, password, registration_date)
VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname', '$sex', '$result', SHA1('$password'), NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
header('Location: ../index.php');
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// close mysql
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Never forget validation of userinputs. Never trust a user. Never ever. All users are evil. More evil than eval can ever be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) on the query to get the data as an array and then access the price appropriately:

```
if ($resource = mysql_query($query))
{

  $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);

  $price = $result['prijs'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

'mysql_query()' function always return array on success.

---

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
    $price = mysql_result($result, 0);
}
```

---

now pass $price in insert query instead of $result

or use " mysql_fetch_array()" function to further retrieve desire data from $result.

Refe:-

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php
2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php